# Determine whether $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, inequality

Let $f(x) = -x + (x^3/3!) + \sin(x)$

How do I determine if $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing?

I have already found the derivative of this function which is:
$f'(x) = -1 + (x^2/2) + \cos(x)$

And I know I have to solve the inequalities for:
$-1 + (x^2/2) + \cos(x) \geq 0$ (increasing)
and
$-1 + (x^2/2) + \cos(x) \leq 0$ (decreasing)

But I am having some problems to solve them.
How should I proceed?

Comment: Looks good so far. Perhaps one approach at least how I would try to solve it is using the graphs. For the increasing case, you want to find out when $\frac{x^2}{2} \geq 1 - \cos(x)$. You can graph that and find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider first the case for $x\geq 0$.

At $x=0$, we have  $f'(x)=−1+(x^2/2)+cos(x)=0$ and $f''(x)= x-sin(x)$ which at $x=0$ is also $0$. But note that for all $x \geq 0$ we have $f'''(x)= 1-cos(x)\geq 0$. So $f''(x)$ is increasing in x. Since $f''(0)=0$, it follows that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. This in turn, implies that $−1+(x^2/2)+cos(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ since $f'(0)=0$.

Since, $f'(x)=f'(-x)$ this establishes that the derivative is always (weakly) positive. You can strengthen it to always strictly positive for all $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really understood it. The others were great too, but yours was the simplest and easiest to understand. Just one more question: can I say that since f''(0) = 0, it follows that f''(x) >= 0 for all x >= 0, so that way the derivative would be positive, instead of strictly positive?

Comment: Given that $f'''(x) \geq 0$, then yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Since $-1\leq \cos(x)\leq 1$, you have $-2\leq \cos(x)-1\leq 0$.  Since $\frac{x^2}{2}\geq 2$ for $x\geq 2$ and $x\leq -2$, your function will increase on those intervals.  So, you need to only consider $-2\leq x\leq 2$.  Both $\cos(x)$ and $\frac{x^2}{2}$ are even functions.  This allows us to only consider $-2\leq x\leq 0$.  On this interval $\cos(x)$ is an increasing function.  Thus $\cos(x)-1$ is also increasing.  In addition $\frac{x^2}{2}$ is increasing.  Since $-1+\cos(-2)+\frac{(-2)^2}{2}> 0$, the derivative must be greater than $0$ for all of $-2\leq x<0$.

Comment: I understand the logic you are using here. The only part I am having trouble understanding is why cos(x) and x^2/2 being even functions allow us to only consider -2 <= x <= 0 instead of -2 <= x <= 2. Can you explain me that?

Comment: @LucasPG even $\implies f'(x)=f'(-x)$, so what is true on the sub interval is true for the whole interval.

Answer (score 2):

As $f$ is odd, we need to study only the case $x\ge0$, if it is increasing, the same will be valid for corresponding regions in the negative axis also.

Now we have $\cos x \le 1 \implies 1-\cos x \ge 0$. Integrating this from $0$ to $x$ successively will give you the result you seek... i.e.

$$\implies \int_0^x (1-\cos x) dx = x -\sin x \ge 0$$

$$\implies \int_0^x(x-\sin x) dx = \frac{x^2}2+\cos x -1\ge 0$$

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think of finding the roots of the derivative and then determining if the function is positive of negative to the left and right of the roots. 
$$f'(x) = −1+(x^2/2)+\cos(x)$$
Use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to find the roots and see when it is positive and negative.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with factoring using a sub-multiple trig ratio as it leads to verifying signs of $\sin(x)\over{x}$ to solve the inequalities which seems pretty natural to me

$-1+\frac{x^2}{2}+cos(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}-2sin^2(\frac{x}{2}) \ge 0$

$\implies x^2 - 4sin^2(\frac{x}{2}) \ge 0$

$\implies (x-2sin(\frac{x}{2}))(x+2sin(\frac{x}{2})) \ge 0$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation). Also, I cannot understand what you are trying to do in the answer!